# How to fix parsing error in my yaml file?

Tags: yaml, circleci

I keep getting the error of "expected <
block end> but found < block mapping start>

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
   test:
     machine:
          enabled: true
     steps:
        - run: echo "Test can run here!"
   deploy:
      machine:
          enabled: true
   handlers:
       - url: /favicon\.ico
         static_files: favicon.ico
         upload: favicon\.ico
       - url: /static
         static_dir: public
       - url: /.*
         secure: always
         redirect_http_response_code: 301
         script: auto
    steps:
         - run:
              name: Install Java & Maven
              command: ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y curl git && sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && sudo apt-get install -y maven" 
         - run:
              name: Clone Repo & Install Application Dependencies
              command: ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "git clone https://www.github.com && cd ~/some-file-path"
         - run:
              name: Deploy Application
              command: ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd ~/some-file-path && mvn verify"
         - run:
              name: Run application 
              command: ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd ~/some-file-path && mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true spring-boot:run" 
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  test-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - test
      - handlers
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - test
            - handlers
```

I have gone through quite a few of the previously asked questions on here and tried some different indentation, but can't seem to find the fix for this.

Edit: Error code in full

While parsing a block mapping

in 'string', line 3, column 4: test:

expected block end, but found 'block mapping start'

in 'string', line 6, column 5: steps:

Edit 2: I thought I would add a screenshot of my code in a text editor. I am new to yaml, so I am finding it hard to see where exactly the indentation is incorrect, it really looks fine to me.

[screenshot of code in text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EyDz.png)

Comment: line 21 `   steps:` has one space too much

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I tried that, but the error is still there. I will edit my post to add the error in full

Comment: `steps` starts at column 6 but the error message says „column 5“. Check whether you accidentally have a TAB in there and replace it by space.

Comment: @flyx is this error saying that steps on should start on column 4 instead of 5? I really don't understand what it is saying exactly.

Comment: Step has to be on the same indentation level as `machine`. Since indentation is frequently scrambled what pasting into SO, I am not sure what the original file looks like, but the problem is likely that the indentation of `steps` is not what it needs to be.

Comment: I've rewritten the file and the error message just moves from column to column. It's the same error, but it's line 3, column 5: test: and line 21, column 9: steps: I have steps in line with machine now. I just can't see the issue, everything looks like it's in line (it's obviously not)

Comment: No it now also moved to a different line. Line 21 is new, the `steps` there also has the wrong indentation (must be on the same level as `handlers`).